# Stupid question about the cross-ratio

Tags: complex-analysis

A quick and very stupid question, but what does it mean that the cross-ratio is real? (coming from the complex analysis angle, Mobius transformations and all that), is it that (z, z1, z2, z3) are all real? That it maps the real line to the real line? Something else entirely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: googling like crazy, can only find statements that start with "the cross ratio is real iff..." etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross ratio, denoted by $(z_1,z_2;z_3, z_4)$ is defined to be the image of $z_4$ under the linear fractional transformation that sends $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $\infty,0,1$ respectively.  So to say that this real means that the image is $\mathbb{R}$.